# integral of Fractional function

Tags: indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

***What is the solution to this integral?***
This integral is attached in the equation below.

\begin{eqnarray*}
\int \frac{dx}{Ax^n+Bx+c}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I don't see a general solution for this, mainly since for $n\geq{5}$, we have no general equation for the roots of $Ax^n+Bx+c$.

Comment: Is there no general solution for the n value of less than 5?

Comment: Try each case: factorize the denominator, split in partial fractions and integrate.

Comment: @3pi.sahagh : Probably the reason some people have down-voted the question is that they thought it was in the kind of language suitable for assigning homework (even thought it's not a reasonable homework question unless it's in an unusual context). If you include something in the question about how you came to be thinking about this, that might help.

Comment: You'd probably have to find roots of the polynomial numerically, and use that to factor the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

If the polynomial $A x^n + B x + c$ has $n$ distinct complex roots $r_1, \ldots, r_n$, then
the integral can be written as
$$ \sum_{j=1}^n \dfrac{\ln(x - r_j)}{n A r_j^{n-1} + B} + \text{constant}$$